# how do i send a method in a template class a print function from main c++

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, pointer-to-member

This is the print function I'm trying to use but it is not working. Currently it is in the main() file but outside main() itself. I keep getting a 
c2228: left of ".data" must have class/struct/union
I'm not a pro at coding at all and am having trouble figuring this out. Because it's a template I'm assuming p isn't anything yet and cannot be passed to the inorder function the problem is how do I solve this I cannot find anything that's even close to my understanding. please give an example or solution that would work and is as close to noob level as possible. THANK YOU!

```
template <class Entry>
void print(Entry&);
template <class Entry>
void print(Entry& p)
{
    cout << p.data << endl;
}
```

this is the function I am trying to use. I need to do an iterative inorder traversal of an AVL Tree and use this passed print function to visit and print the data from the nodes.

declaration

```
void inorder(void(*visit)(Entry &));
```

implementation

```
template<class Entry>
inline void Binarytree<Entry>::inorder(void(*visit)(Entry &))
{
}
```

call in main()

```
tree.inorder(print);
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the `Entry` type you use in your binary tree doesn't have a member called `data`. What are the entries in your tree? ints, or some class?

In any case, here is an example for code that compiles:

```
template <class Entry>
void print(Entry& p)
{
    std::cout << p.data << std::endl;
}

template<class Entry>
class BinaryTree
{
public:
    vector<Entry> items;
    inline void inorder(void(*visit)(Entry &))
    {
        for (auto& it : items)
        {
            visit(it);
        }
    }
};

class SomeType
{
public:
    int data;
};

int main()
{
    BinaryTree<SomeType> a;
    a.inorder(print);
}
```